# SSIS package failing

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I am using SSIS for data warehousing to import data from different sources like flat files,.xls and some other SQL server servers. 
In my scenario i have 50 data flow task which execute in a package(Control flow) parallel.These data flow are independent means fetching data from different tables and files into my warehouse DB.
In my case sometime structure of my source table or file changed and then my package got failed means show validation error.

I need a solution by which I can skip only corrupted "data flow task" and other data flow task can complete their task. I don't like to make separate package for each data flow task.

Please advise what to do in such situation.

Regards

Shakti

Comment: And this structure is changing often?

Answer (score 1):

I highly advise putting each of these into a separate package, and then using a scheduling tool or master package to call each one individually. It will make the maintainability of this solution much better.

If you insist on having them all in one package, you can use the "FailParentOnFailure", "FailPackageOnFailure", and "MaximumErrorCount" properties to have your data flow fail, but the container ignore errors, allowing other things to run. Really probably shouldn't do that though - failures could be for any number of reasons and having separate packages that run in parallel makes finding the error during a scheduled run much easier...